# Subtracting date using DATEDIFF function and getting NULL as results

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm tasked with finding the delay in weeks for each order. I've used the `DATEDIFF` function and I'd like to believe I'm on the right track but when I use it I get `NULL` as the result. The data type for each column are both date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sales.Orders.custid, Sales.Customers.companyname,
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 7 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 14 THEN '1 Week'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 14 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 21 THEN '2 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 21 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 28 THEN '3 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 28 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 35 THEN '4 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 35 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 42 THEN '5 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) = 42 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 49 THEN '6 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) > 49 THEN '7+ Weeks'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS Order_Delay
FROM Sales.Orders, Sales.Customers
ORDER BY 
Order_Delay ASC;
```

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: If you're using MS SQL, why did you tag the question with MySQL?

Comment: `=7 and <14` - is there any chance that `7` becomes `>=14`? Did you mean `>=7` ? `<49` and `> 49` = lost `49`

Comment: And, of course, why not `floor(datediff(dd...) / 7)`

Comment: and you might want to join the tables properly, you have just created a Cartesian product of those 2 tables, I would not trust the current results at all. Not surprising you added `distinct` to reduce the number os rows, but that doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the floor function and how it would be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sales.Orders.custid, Sales.Customers.companyname,
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) >= 7 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 14 THEN '1 Week'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 21 THEN '2 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 28 THEN '3 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 35 THEN '4 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 42 THEN '5 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 49 THEN '6 Weeks'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) >= 49 THEN '7+ Weeks'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS Order_Delay
FROM Sales.Orders, Sales.Customers
ORDER BY 
Order_Delay ASC;
```

I think you want to check whether difference is in particular range (from 7 to 14, etc.).

So I corrected first cndition:

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) >= 7 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY, Sales.Orders.shippeddate, Sales.Orders.orderdate) < 14 THEN '1 Week'
```

You could not use `BETWEEN` here, as its range includes also broders of a set.

For other cases, you don't need to check whether the difference is greater than, eg. in second `WHEN` you know that the difference is `>=14`, since it failed first condition, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`FROM Sales.Orders, Sales.Customers` is an old-fashioned way of forming a `cross join`. This is probably accidental but the impact of this can be awful both in terms of performance but also the results can be plain wrong - and they are in your example. It is for this reason that I always recommend you use explicit join syntax such as `inner join` and **cease using commas** as a way to define the from clause.

You simply have to properly join the 2 tables, otherwise every order is applied to every customer and the results would be quite wrong. I have guessed that join, but it should look something like the one seen below:

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT ?? */
    Sales.Orders.custid
  , Sales.Customers.companyname
  , CASE
        WHEN ca.Order_Delay >= 7 THEN '7+ Weeks'
        WHEN ca.Order_Delay >= 1 AND ca.Order_Delay < 7 THEN CAST(ca.Order_Delay AS varchar) + ' Weeks'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS order_delay
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Sales.Customers AS c ON o.custid = c.id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.shippeddate, o.orderdate) / 7)
    ) ca (order_delay)
ORDER BY
    order_delay ASC
;
```

In SQL Server is possible to use `cross apply` as a way to perform a calculation, and give that calculation an alias that you can then use in the select clause. This can have the effect of making your code somewhat easier to read, but this is optional.

Above I have suggested a way to use `floor()` which you should read about here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

nb: If you want to show data for unshipped orders then you may need to change to an `outer apply`, and if an order is unshipped  the the `datediff()` function would return NULL and your `case expression` would need to explicitly cater for NULLs

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT ?? */
    Sales.Orders.custid
  , Sales.Customers.companyname
  , CASE
        WHEN ca.Order_Delay >= 7 THEN '7+ Weeks'
        WHEN ca.Order_Delay >= 1 AND ca.Order_Delay < 7 THEN CAST(ca.Order_Delay AS varchar) + ' Weeks'
        WHEN ca.Order_Delay IS NULL then 'Unshipped'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS order_delay
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Sales.Customers AS c ON o.custid = c.id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.shippeddate, o.orderdate) / 7)
    ) ca (order_delay)
ORDER BY
    order_delay ASC
;
```

Comment: I made the changes and now I'm just getting unknown as the result.

Comment: Suggest you swap the 2 dates inside the datediff function as suggested below by ,Ivan Starostin. If the datediff result is negative then the else condition is the one that works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

My guess is that in your system `shippeddate` is mostly **later** or equal to `orderdate`, so instead of

`FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.shippeddate, o.orderdate) / 7)`

you might want

`FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate) / 7)`

to check this assumption you might want to add `ca.Order_Delay` (as per code suggested by @Used_by_already) to list of selected columns and see what values are there. My bet is they are all negative.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for exactly 7, 14, 21 etc.  You need >= 7 instead (and repeat for the rest...).

Comment: While you are correct about the edit that is required, that doesn't explain `NULL` values as there is an `ELSE` clause on the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Nick Then the OP isn't showing us the whole picture.  That CASE expressions can't ever return NULL.

Comment: @MatBailie indeed. But that **never** happens on SO! :)